# Nginx 302 redirect loop debugging

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have more than 50+ location match directives in my web application nginx file. after making some changes, i am stuck with a 302 redirect loop on one location directive called /login. it keep redirecting to 302 /login and never gets out. is there any way in nginx directives that i can setup a breakpoint, a log, that from which location directives the request passes? so i get an idea that which is the faulty redirect or location source?

i dont think the debug log gives this information.

In short, what is the best way to Trace the request precisely and in very detailed way among whole configuration

Comment: Remove server and http level  log directives from the nginx configuration and add to the location level each with a different name.

Comment: @Drifter104: i did , but still only one log file is getting logs, others are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have 50+ location match directives?  The correct solution might be to use the `map` directive instead.

The correct way to debug the changes having unintended consequences is to do revision control of your changes:

- If a whole bunch of changes were made, and never tested in-between, then you can use something like [`git-bisect`](//git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) to find out the offending directive.
- If you already know the offending change, then carefully examining each part should reveal the issue.

However, based on the hostname from your screenshot, and examining the response of your server:

```
curl -v -k https://www.groupsitedev.com/login | & sed -E "s#^#`printf \\t`#g"
…
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: nginx/1.13.3
< Date: Sun, 27 Aug 2017 02:21:44 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Runtime: 2
< Location: https://www.groupsitedev.com/login
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: _session_id=882afb51754b1cd5deef94cb65457625; domain=.groupsitedev.com; path=/
< 
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://www.groupsitedev.com/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

…, reveals that this issue is likely not related to nginx, and is likely performed upstream:

- it's very unlikely that you've modified the default nginx 302 handler to provide text like `<html><body>You are being <a href="https://www.groupsitedev.com/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>`, which is not the default; and a redirect from an inefficient upstream is much more likely (nginx wouldn't provide such custom text (with a hyperlink) because it's inefficient to copy the URL multiple times like that, into a web-page that no modern browser will ever show up anyway)
- it's very unlikely that you've configured nginx to issue session cookies, all by itself; a cookie from your upstream is much more likely.

Thus, ***in summary***, there is nothing to debug in nginx — the redirect is clearly coming from your upstream, which you've revealed to us nothing about.

Comment: Actually i have a compelx application, it has 2 backends. so i have to perform routing based on URLs, to send certain URLs to goto different backends

Comment: when i send request directly from ngin to backed, i get this in log
GET 200 "GET /login HTTP/1.1" {-} | [upstream 172.18.0.6:3002 | 200] [proxies=52.5.119.172, 127.0.0.1]
 GET 200 "GET /login HTTP/1.1" {-} | [upstream 127.0.0.1:8080 | 200] [proxies=52.5.119.172]

Comment: @Farhan, I have no idea what that means, it sounds like you may have an unnecessarily complex application setup; overall, the best way to debug 302 redirects is change one of them at a time, to introduce some extra parameters; otherwise, a good way to see what's going on between multiple backends is to examine one at a time through a tool like [`tcpdump`](http://mdoc.su/o/tcpdump)

Comment: the issue is resolved. it was application issue. the application received protocol mismatch. i had to tell it one fixed https protocol in nginx.

Comment: thanks for your help. digging deeped, i found that applications logs are accepting ptocotocol mismatch

Comment: @Farhan, it might be helpful for the next person to know what the application was, and what caused it to have protocol mismatch — sounds like a one-liner anyways.

Comment: Application is made on Ruby on rails. before there was a proxy between app and user. now i removed that proxy, which was passing all http and http requests to app. but after removing the proxy, i had to make sure that it receives proper protocol scheme, it is meant to reply to.

Comment: @Farhan, right; so, what was the exact code you used to put back the protocol scheme?

Comment: i changed it to  "proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;" from "proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;"

Answer (score 2):

Within each of your location blocks, add a header that's unique to that block. Using those headers you can work out which block is selected by Nginx, that can help you debug.

```
# Recommended
location / {
  add_header Z_LOCATION "home";
}

location /admin/ {
  add_header Z_LOCATION "admin";
}
```

You can use a single header name if you want to, but I wonder if rewrites or forwarding or such could obscure the path through the system so I don't do it.

```
# NOT recommended
location / {
  add_header Z_LOCATION "home";
}

location /admin/ {
  add_header Z_LOCATION "admin";
}
```

View the URL / page using Firefox with the [Live HTTP Headers plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/), or "curl -i". The header you added will tell you which block(s) it hits. The advantage of Live HTTP Headers over curl is you don't need to keep issuing commands, Firefox will follow the redirects and show you the headers for each request / response.

You need the headers_more module in Nginx for add_header to work. You can check if you have it included with "nginx -V". If you don't it's relatively easy to [build Nginx from source](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source).

I found this technique incredibly helpful when I was learning Nginx, and getting my websites set up.

Comment: I cannot see that information in the header. 
this is what i get: http://prntscr.com/gdes1p

Comment: "location" wasn't a good choice for header name as it's used for other things. See my edit. This technique works very well. If you can't get it working work from first principles - an Nginx server with one location block that serves a static page, then add the add_header directive. Once you have that working build back up to your full config.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. but i am still not able to find source of 302, that why its stuck in 302 redirect. could you please provide some help or tips on how to detect the redirect and stop it there? and then fix it?

Comment: this is what i get: http://prntscr.com/gdglwc

Comment: I think you need to read my answer again, I've used this technique many times to debug Nginx location issues and it works very well. The idea is you add a header that Nginx sends, then you use Firefox or curl showing response headers to see what location blocks it hits. Also, if you edit your question to add your Nginx server block configuration to the question someone might be able to spot the problem.